# Best practice for building file paths in C#

Tags: c#, file, path, concatenation

I'm working on a C# project where I must build paths to various files and folders.  These are all under one root folder which I have specified in my Web.config file.

For example:

1. "start with: "D:\builds\" from my Web.config
2. Pass to GetRelativePath() to get "D:\builds\5.2\5.2.9751"
3. Then pass to GetAutoSuitePath() to get "D:\builds\5.2\5.2.9751\AutoSuite\"
4. Then pass to ParseBrLog which will read "D:\builds\5.2\5.2.9751\AutoSuite\AASanity.csv"

My paths are correct, but I just want to know what the best practice is for incomplete paths.  Should I add a "\" to the end of every folder ("D:\Builds\5.2\" + "test.txt"), or add one to the start of every folder/file I add to the path ("D:\Builds" + "\5.2" + "\test.txt")?  Currently, I'm, doing it both ways, and want to choose one uniform way of doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I join two paths in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961704/how-do-i-join-two-paths-in-c)*.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class to build up your paths. It will do the right thing.

> Performs operations on String instances that contain file or directory path information. These operations are performed in a cross-platform manner.

```
var full = Path.Combine(baseDir, dirFragment);
```

Comment: using System.IO (for C# amateurs like me)

Answer (score 9):

Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to concatenate path tokens.

If the path is a file to set/change the extension use [Path.ChangeExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension).