# How to get file path from folder wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having an issue, I am developing a WPF application where I have one page named as "help" having one button **go**
 When user clicks on this button I have to provide pdf file to the user which is in the help folder.
Now my problem is if I write path like this

```
**string pdfurl1 = ((@"D:\addnkit\projects\wdine\widdne_working\Wdine Us\Wddine\Wine\Help\Emerald Wine Dispensing Software.pdf"));
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfurl1);**
```

Its working successfully

but I know this will not going to work in other pcs so I want to know how can I write code for the same that can be run on any pcs

I have also tried like this

```
(@"pack://application:,,,/Widne;component/help/mypdf.pdf"
```

But its not working

[Updated]

I have tried all the solutions but its not working yet I don't know why?
please check once again
***Widne >> Help >> mypdf***

[image]

Comment: What folder is your .exe in?

Comment: the Widne in your exe directory ?

Comment: this directory will be existing in uour debug directory ? are this directory in your main project ?

Comment: No i am not showing you debug direcotry yes this directory is in a main project

Comment: this directory will be existing in uour debug directory ? this question to Konw if this directory help will be create in with your exe in the same directory ?

Comment: Yes its creating this folder in my debug directory i see it but this pdf file does not exists there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the path of your exe

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
             + "\\Widne\\component\\help\\mypdf.pdf";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path )
```

**Update :**

befor opning the file he must be existing, in this case you make the property to your PDF file `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`

Comment: check updated i don't know why its still not working

Comment: @dholakiyaankit I update my answer  check that and reply

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd method `packuri` is what you should use.

Your problem is most likely that your `mypdf.pdf` needs to have it's properties changed in Visual Studio so that it actually copies the pdf file when built and not embed in the application preventing the end-user from reading the pdf file.

Set these properties on the pdf file and rebuild the application

> Build Action: Content
>   Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

Edit: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145769/1992193) for an explanation of Build Action.

Comment: Please explain me more

Comment: check updated i don't know why its still not working

Comment: Thanks i just can not get you that's all

Answer (score 2):

The `Diagnostics.Process`class has nothing to do with WPF. If the path is relative to your application, you can use relative paths. If you fear that the application is run with a working directory different to the directory where the assembly is stored, you can query the original folder of that assembly using

```
 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

and construct the path to the PDF with `Path.Combine`.

Comment: check updated i don't know why its still not working

Comment: You need to get the directory name - CodeBase gives you the .exe file. `string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),  @"PrintTemplates\Promotions\images\promotion1.png");`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a relative path:

```
./ - start at the .exe directory

../ - go up one folder from the .exe

../../ - go up two folders etc.
```

EDIT:

Assuming your .exe in in the bin folder:

```
**string pdfurl1 = ((@"..\Help\Emerald Wine Dispensing Software.pdf"));
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfurl1);**
```

Comment: check updated i don't know why its still not working

Comment: @dholakiyaankit see edit. Where is your .exe located?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. That will give you the directory from where the application was launched. So if you place your file where the application was launched it would be something like this:

```
string pdfurl1 = ((Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\Emerald Wine Dispensing Software.pdf"));
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfurl1);
```

Comment: check updated i don't know why its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704579/best-practice-for-building-file-paths) can help you

Use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class to build up your paths. It will do the right thing.

> Performs operations on String instances that contain file or directory
>   path information. These operations are performed in a cross-platform
>   manner.

```
var full = Path.Combine(baseDir, dirFragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Directory Dialog to get the Directory Path, First Add reference System.Windows.Forms, and then Resolve, and then put this code in a button click.

```
        var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        folderpathTB.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
```

(folderpathTB is name of TextBox where I wana put the folder path, OR u can assign it to a string variable too i.e.)

```
        string folder = dialog.SelectedPath;
```

---

---

And if you wana get FileName/path, Simply do this on Button Click

```
        FileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.ShowDialog();
        folderpathTB.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
```

(folderpathTB is name of TextBox where I wana put the file path, OR u can assign it to a string variable too)

Note: For Folder Dialog, the System.Windows.Forms.dll must be added to the project, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this code:

```
string pdfFolder;

#if DEBUG
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName);
            pdfFolder = directoryInfo.FullName + @"\PdfFile\Auto Refill Reminder List.pdf";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfFolder );
#endif

#if (!DEBUG)
            pdfFolder = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\PdfFile\Auto Refill Reminder List.pdf";
            Process.Start(pdfFolder);
#endif
```

And change the build type of your content:

[image]