# Cannot find file path

Tags: c#, path, windows-ce, c#-2.0, relative-path

I'm using Windows CE 6.0. I'm developping an application that needs to read a XML file (bar.xml) that is placed right next to my executable (foo.exe).

I try to access it with the following method, called right after my Main() :

```
private void ParseXmlFile(string _sFileName)
{
    XmlDocument l_doc = new XmlDocument();
    l_doc.Load(_sFileName);
}
```

Now, when launching my application from the Windows CE console with :

```
foo.exe bar.xml
```

All I receive is an exception stating : Cound not find file '\bar. Notice the '\' here. I also tried :

```
foo.exe bar.xml
foo.exe .\bar.xml
foo.exe ./bar.xml
```

My application is under \Hard Disk\ftp\Test\

If I put my file under the "Hard Disk" folder, everything is fine. Of course, I don't want my file here. How can I tell my application to look up this file in the same folder as my application ?

**Edit :** 
After comment from @Thomas, I checked my path and saw that I was indeed in the correct folder (\Hard Disk\ftp\Test).

I had to use the following code to get the path (because of Compact framework 2.0) :

```
string l_sFullAppName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
string l_sFullAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(l_sFullAppName);

XmlDocument l_doc = new XmlDocument();
l_doc.Load(_l_sFullAppPath + '\\bar.xml');
```

It works but doesn't seem to be very convenient to me. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Check with [Application.executablepath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx) if your application is really executed where you think it is.

Comment: It's a console application, I cannot have Application.executablepath. I tried following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application) but I can't get the Location property. I don't know why. My System.dll reference is under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\System.dll" and is indeed in version 2.0.

Comment: @leppie I specified c#-2.0 because I absolutely need framework 2.0. Is that wrong ?

Comment: And this :`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];` ?

Comment: I don't have it, I guess it's because I'm using the framework 2.0 of compact framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Determine full executable directory. See [HOW TO: Determine the Executing Application's Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx). The contents is applicable to .NET Compact Framework.  [Note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.codebase(v=vs.80).aspx), that `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase` returns  location of the assembly as a URL, but `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returns full path or UNC location (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx)).
2. Use [Path.Combine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) method for combining strings into a result path.

As result your code may be like this:

```
var fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var fullFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(fullPath, _sFileName);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know about Path.Combine(), I simply used string concatenation to add my filename to my filepath. That is interesting. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem. Usage of `Path.Combine()` is the best practice to combine a path strings. For example see answer to [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704579/best-practice-for-building-file-paths).