# C#: Dispose() a Bitmap object after call Bitmap.save()?

Tags: c#, bitmap, dispose

I have this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
//image processing
bmp.Save(path + fileName);
```

and I want to know if I need to call `bmp.Dispose()` after this code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `using` block and `Path.Combine`

```
using(var bmp = new Bitmap(image))
{
    // image processing
    bmp.Save(Path.Combine(path ,fileName));
}
```

Comment: it is better to use when you join paths like this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961704/how-do-i-join-two-paths-in-c

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

Better yet, you could wrap your bmp in a using block, this will take care of the disposal for you

```
using(var bmp = new Bitmap(image))
{
    bmp.Save(...);
}
```

[Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx)'s sole purpose is to save the image to the specified file, it doesn't change the bitmap object

Answer (score 4):

There's a simple rule: if you've *created* a disposable instance and haven't passed it to another ower, you should *dispose* it. In your code; since you've *created* Bitmap you're supposed to *dispose* it as well:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image)) { // <- Creation
  // Image processing
  ...
  bmp.Save(path + fileName);
} // <- You no longer need the bitmap, let's dispose it
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're done with it: yes. Based simply on the fact that

- it implements `IDisposable`, and
- you're done with it

To be honest, those two points are *essentially* the entire debate - everything else is implementation details. Although in this case the implementation details are probably GDI+ handles, which are definitely worth cleaning up properly. But you can make your life easier with `using`:

```
using(var bmp = new Bitmap(image))
{
    // image processing
    bmp.Save(path + fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to call `Dispose()` method, otherwise bitmap recources being in use before garbage collertor calls finalizer method.
Just use the `using` operator:

```
using(var bmp = new Bitmap(image))

    {
        // image processing
        bmp.Save(path + fileName);
    }
```