# Files and Directory C#

Tags: c#

Been working on file directory stuff in C# and I think i might just be forgetting something simple here. So lets says I have 4 folders and I need to check if the folder exists and then display the files within the folder. But the part that I'm stuck at is checking lets say the creationdate of a file WITH one of the four folders. Almost like I'm missing the path actual path to the file within the folder. Here the code that i had so far.

> ```
>         string end;
>         string directoryName;
>         string fileName;
>         string[] listOfFiles;
>
>         Console.Write("Enter the name of the folder: ");
>         directoryName = Console.ReadLine();
>         while (directoryName != "end")
>         {
>             if (Directory.Exists(directoryName))
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine("Directory exists, and it contains the following:");
>                 listOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName);
>                 for (int x = 0; x < listOfFiles.Length; ++x)
>                     Console.WriteLine("   {0}", listOfFiles[x]);
>
>             }
>
>             Console.Write("Enter a filename: ");
>             fileName = Console.ReadLine();
>             if(File.Exists(fileName)) // Almost like a path needs to be here.
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine("File was created " + File.GetCreationTime(fileName));
>             }
>         }
> ```

just thought incase it was asked the programs exe and folders are all located together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) takes a full path (just like pretty much every other Filesystem API).

Add the path with [`Path.Combine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx). See [How do I join two paths in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961704/how-do-i-join-two-paths-in-c)

```
fileName = Console.ReadLine();
var filePath = Path.Combine(directoryName, fileName);
if (File.Exists(filePath)) // Almost like a path needs to be here - Yep!
```