# Most efficient way to retrieve one file path from a list of folders

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a list of over 100 folder paths. I would like to retrieve just one file path from each folder path. Here is the way I am doing it or plan to do it :

```
var Files = new List<String>();
var Directories = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Firstfolder\\Secondfolder\\");
Array.ForEach(Directories, D => Files.Add(Directory.GetFiles(D).FirstOrDefault()));
```

Now, is this the most effiecient way? Because My program will execute this code every time it starts.

Comment: FYI and slightly OT: use @"C:\Firstfolder\Secondfolder\" for avoiding double, and hard-to-read, back slashes. If you are doing path manipulation do use [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961704/how-do-i-join-two-paths-in-c](Path.Combine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .Net 4.0 you should do this instead...

```
var Files = Directories.SelectMany(x => Directory.EnumerateFiles(x).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice... Short and Effiecient. I hope :)

Comment: Oops... I guess I should test the code before excepting it. But not big deal I like the Idea .... I have to change the code as follows it to work.        var Files = String.Join("", Directories.SelectMany(x => Directory.EnumerateFiles(x).FirstOrDefault())).Split(new String[] {"C:\\"} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Directory.GetFiles` use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid loading all file paths into memory.This quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx) explains the difference:

> The `EnumerateFiles` and `GetFiles` methods differ as follows: When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use `GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

Comment: You can note, that `GetFiles`  returns array, which is eager. `EnumerateFiles` returns `IEnumerable` which is lazy (potentially)